# How to find where a library is installed?

Tags: package-management

I have installed libgoogle-perftools-dev via software center in Ubuntu 12.04. As suggested by http://pj.freefaculty.org/blog/?p=140, I want to add to my cpp file:

```
#include <gperftools/profiler.h>
```

But the compiler says

```
 gperftools/profiler.h: No such file or directory
```

I tried to find where it is:

```
$ locate -i gperftools
```

no return, and

```
$ locate -i "profiler.h"
```

returns

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/profile/impl/profiler.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic-pae/include/config/function/profiler.h
```

which I am not sure if are for `gperftools`.

So I wonder how to find

- where libgoogle-perftools-dev is installed?
- where gperftools/profiler.h is located?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably the issue with the `locate` command is that the database has not yet been updated to reflect the newly-installed package files. You could force an update (`sudo updatedb`) or use the `find` command instead, but probably the easiest solution on systems like Ubuntu that use the `dpkg` package management tools is to list the package contents

```
dpkg -L libgoogle-perftools-dev
```

or to check for the `profiler.h` file location specifically

```
dpkg -L libgoogle-perftools-dev | grep 'profiler.h'
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually, pkg-config helps in most of these cases
`pkg-config --list-all` lists packages that are "known" to your system. And then `pkg-config --libs --cflags <package>` is good enough to provide linker and include information.