# pkg-config --libs --cflags not return anything for libgoogle-perftools-dev

Tags: libraries, pkg-config

[user2702245](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129501/674) said

> `pkg-config --clibs --flags <package>` is good enough to provide linker
>   and include information.

I tried to find out such information about libgoogle-perftools-dev I installed from software center in Ubuntu 12.04.

```
$ pkg-config --libs --cflags libgoogle-perftools-dev
Package libgoogle-perftools-dev was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libgoogle-perftools-dev.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libgoogle-perftools-dev' found
```

Not found for `libgoogle-perftools`, `libgoogle`, or `perftools` either.

So I wonder how to find the correct name of libgoogle-perftools-dev so that `pkg-config --libs --cflags` can return something? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the `libgoogle-perftools-dev` [list of files](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/amd64/libgoogle-perftools-dev/filelist) and is right. That package doesn't include any pkg-config file to list the headers and libraries of the packages.

You can fill a bug report if you feel this isn't correct.

Comment: what files should the package include so that pkg-config can find it?

Comment: @Tim pkg-config ones, the man has an example to make one yourself.

Comment: what do "pkg-config ones" look like?

Comment: @Tim in `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/` there are some. The man page also includes one.

Comment: .pc files? /usr/lib/pkgconfig/ only has very few pc files. What other files did you look for in https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/amd64/libgoogle-perftools-dev/filelist?